# Are there any other way to restart to recovery HD

Tags: mac, restart

I tried to restart while keep pressing Command-R

However, my keyboard is not mac keyboard. There is windows-R. It works exactly like Command-R in all circumstances.

Well, I keep failing to get into recovery HD. I need that because I want to repair the main disk.

> Error: This disk needs to be repaired using the Recovery HD. Restart
>   your computer, holding down the Command key and the R key until you
>   see the Apple logo. When the OS X Utilities window appears, choose
>   Disk Utility.

What should I do?

I have a flash disk. Can I turn that into recovery HD?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this alternative way (explained at [macworld.com](http://www.macworld.com/article/1167870/hands_on_with_mountain_lions_os_x_recovery_and_internet_recovery.html)):

1. Start you Mac while pressing the <kbd>Option</kbd> key (in your Windows keyboard press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key) until the Startup Manager appears:

   [image]

   One of the volumes will be called Recovery HD.
2. Select Recovery HD and then click the upward-pointing arrow below it to boot from Recovery HD.
3. After a brief delay, you’ll see the Mac OS X Utilities screen. Select Disk Utility to repair your disk:

[image]

Comment: The asker uses a Windows keyboard -> shouldn't he use the ALT key there?

Comment: @patrix Yes, added reference to Alt.

Comment: There is a windows key too that function like command key but that one doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that. For the method I describe you don't need the Windows key, but the Alt key. Did you have a chance to test it?

Comment: I did. And it still doesn't work.

Comment: It looks like the whole keyboard is not detected until restart and by that time it's too late. In windows I can restart to something else or something.

Comment: Too bad... Is it by any chance a wireless keyboard? Could you post keyboard manufacturer and model? Have you installed any keyboard drivers?

Comment: It's USB. Also I changed keyboard again. It still doesn't work.

Comment: I could get hold of a PC keyboard (HP USB keyboard model number KU-0316), restarted my Mac while holding down the Alt key and it booted into the Startup Manager as shown in the screenshot above. Which is the keyboard manufacturer and model you are using?

Comment: None of these solutions worked for me. I am using a wireless keyboard that uses its own USB dongle rather than standard bluetooth, and maybe that's why. But unfortunately, this does leave me dead in the water, unless I'm willing to shell out the money for a mac keyboard I only need to enter recovery mode, which isn't a great prospect.

Answer (score 9):

Note for other who come across this thread. To get into Internet Recovery Mode I used <kbd>WINDOWS</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> on my 2011 Mac Mini while powering back on. <kbd>CONTROL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> did not work for me with a Windows Keyboard (USB).

Comment: This helped me. Also on another thread, waiting 2-3 seconds after the chime before you press the buttons. Then it works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

I tried this with a bluetooth windows keyboard and the ALT key on the left side of the space bar worked for me. I did not press any other key.

One more thing: it did not work when I did a soft restart; I had to power down, hold the ALT key, then power up the mini.

Comment: This was a life saver!

Comment: Tried this a bunch of times, on multiple keyboards. What helped was plugging a specific keyboard into the other USB port. Weird?... Both ports worked; I just switched mouse and keyboard and finally Alt+R did what it's supposed to.

Answer (score 2):

For a mid 2011 Mac Mini using a bluetooth keyboard, what finally worked for me was the Windows-R key combo.

Answer (score 1):

I had to power off and unplug the Mac Mini then hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and start the Mini up that way and then it works.

Every time I install Sierra I can't log in and have to do this first.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing worked for me until I tried this:

1. Plug USB keyboard in on far right USB port.
2. Shut down Mac Mini.
3. Power on mac mini and wait 3 seconds
4. Hold left ALT down.

Answer (score 0):

I've got an arduino so I'm making it into a fake usb keyboard that outputs the alt button. Really all I can do in lockdown with no shops open!

https://code.google.com/archive/p/unojoy/

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problems.  I have both an old MacBook Pro (2010) and a 2014 Mac Mini.  With the MBP and a built-in keyboard, I can get to the Recovery without difficulty, using any of the specified methods.

The Mini has been entirely different, where the best I can do is a login screen that offers to reset the login password.  For this, I am using not only a Windows keyboard, but also where the keyboard is connected to a KVM switch (i.e., USB connection from the Mini to the switch, and then keyboard attached to the switch).

After a bunch floundering, I found that at least with the Mini, timing is an issue. I had been pressing the specified keys as soon as I could after a restart during the startup chime.  However, if I wait 3 seconds until the chime is done, and then press keys, I can get the recovery console.

I don't know if it's that the Mini is a little different than an MBP, my use of external keyboard through a KVM or a combination, but with the Mini, timing is significant, and it's necessary to wait until after the chime to press keys

Answer (score 0):

If all the above answers don't work for you. Maybe try to hold the windows+r a little bit later when you press the power button. Some keyboards would not be recognized immediately when you press the power on button.